# How do I remove "undefined" when auto-filling a form?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function validate() {
  var errMsg = "";
  var result = true;

  var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
   if (!fname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
        errMsg += "Please enter your first name correctly.\n";
        result = false;
    }
  if (errMsg) {
alert(errMsg);
  }

  if (result) {
  
function storeBooking(
  fname
  ) {
  sessionStorage.fname = fname;
  }
  function getBooking() {
  if (sessionStorage.fname != undefined) {
    document.getElementById("confirm_fname").textContent = sessionStorage.fname;
     }
 }
 
 function prefillcard()
{ 
  document.getElementById("fname").value =  sessionStorage.fname;
  
  }

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", prefillcard);

function init() {
  var regForm = document.getElementById("regform");

  regForm.onsubmit = validate;
}
```

```html
<form action="apply.html" method="post" id="regform">

<label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." required="required" maxlength="25" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) || (event.charCode==32)">
        <input type="submit" value="Apply">
 </form>
```

I've set up some code to auto-fill a form if the user had already filled the form in the same browser session and then revisited the form. The only problem is that there is a placeholder, which you need to delete before putting in an input, is there and I don't know how to get rid of it. "Undefined" comes up when you fill the form in the first time. How do I get rid of this?

Note: no jQuery or inline JavaScript.

Comment: The code that you have posted doesnot demonstrate the issue that you are specifying. Function definition of `validate` is not proper. Please fix the issue and make the code working sothat we can debug the issue..

Answer (score 0):

To store values in session use

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem("Name", Value));
```

and to retrieve value from session use

```
window.sessionStorage.getItem("Name");
```

Sample code below

```
function prefillcard() { 
  if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("fname")) {
   var fnm = window.sessionStorage.getItem("fname");
   document.getElementById("fname").value = fnm;
  }
}
```

and to set Session value use

```
var fnm = document.getElementById("fname").value;
window.sessionStorage.setItem("fname", fnm));
```

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the issue from the code snippet provided in the question?